# How to handle "InvalidOperationException Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple function that returns average sales for a month. However, when a new month begins there are no records and I got the exception below:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements.'

```
public double GetTotalMonthlyAvgSales()
{
    return _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Created.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year).Select(x => x.TotalAmount).Average();

}
```

What is the best way to handle this exception?

Comment: Well, only call `Average()` when there is any element in `_DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Created.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year).Select(x => x.TotalAmount)`? Split the call and check the content with `Any()` is a solution.

Comment: It is probably best to first check if there are matching Cart items using `Any()`. If none, then maybe return `0` or `-1`, but that value is for you to decide. `null` might be a more meaningful response, if you can change the return type to `double?`.

Comment: What would you like to return if there are no records returned from the `where` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would probably be just surrounding the block with a `try ... catch` and return 0 (or whatever other default value you want), if an execption is thrown

```
public double GetTotalMonthlyAvgSales()
{
  try {
    return _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Created.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year).Select(x => x.TotalAmount).Average();
  } catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
    //if it's an InvalidOperationException return 0
    return 0;
  }
  //any other exception will be rethrown
}
```

But as exceptions are expensive, you could check, if the collection you are trying to calculate the average of contains any elements

```
public double GetTotalMonthlyAvgSales()
{
  var col = _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Created.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year);
  if (col.Any()) {
    //if the collection has elements, you can calculate the average
    return col.Select(x => x.TotalAmount).Average();
  }
  //if not, return 0
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking to do it like your second attempt, but I do like the first one more. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I like the second one more. Because an "exception" should be (as the name suggests) something exceptional and should not be used for defining the control flow. And having an empty collection seems to be nothing "exceptional" in your use case, therefore you should try to prevent exceptions. Furthermore exception handling is quite expensive.